# PHP empty curl response when a json value contains a '<'

Tags: php, json, special-characters

i'm trying to read the call history from our pbx via rest-api.
So far i get a valid json response, but in php some values are empty.

on linux commandline, i will get this value for phone numbers, eg:

```
curl -u user:pass -D - https://url/rest/user/10/wallboard/60
```

```
--> Result: "from":"<sip:+1234567890@domain.com>"
```

This is a part of my php script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url/rest/user/10/wallboard/60');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $loginName . ":" . $loginPass);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print ($response);
```

```
--> Result: "from":""
```

I guess the problem is the "<" character in the from value.
Any ideas how to resolve this and get the full phone number?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you running the PHP script through a browser? Then try encode the result: `print_r(htmlentities($response));` so the browser will show the `<` and `>` characters instead of rending them as HTML.

Comment: ok, got it! thanks a lot, that was quite easy!